# Error to install pip on google-cloud

Tags: python, linux, pip, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04

)
I tried to install pip on a gcloud server with ubunto 16.04
I got this error massage. Hopefuly you can help me.

`https://pastebin.com/Pdyt5n5j`

maybe pastbin is better to read.

`root@bascic:~/gcloudstuff# sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils build-essential cpp cpp-5 dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-5 gcc gcc-5 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan2 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5
  libdpkg-perl libexpat1-dev libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0
  libmpc3 libmpx0 libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libtsan0
  libubsan0 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev python-all python-all-dev python-dev python-pip-whl python-setuptools
  python-wheel python2.7-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-5-locales debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-5-multilib gcc-5-doc libstdc++6-5-dbg
  gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-5-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg
  libatomic1-dbg libasan2-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
  glibc-doc libstdc++-5-doc make-doc python-setuptools-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils build-essential cpp cpp-5 dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-5 gcc gcc-5 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan2 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5
  libdpkg-perl libexpat1-dev libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0
  libmpc3 libmpx0 libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libtsan0
  libubsan0 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev python-all python-all-dev python-dev python-pip python-pip-whl
  python-setuptools python-wheel python2.7-dev
0 upgraded, 49 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 837 kB/69.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 192 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.4.0-71.92
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.158.31.252 80]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.4.0-71.92
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.158.31.252 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-71.92_amd64.deb  404  Not F
ound [IP: 192.158.31.252 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue right now. Any progress on this yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have seen the same error message, but could solve it by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Afterwards, I could install pip/pip3 without any issue:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```